# -Thought Experiment- At superluminal speeds, to what degree would vision be impaired?

Tags: speed-of-light, faster-than-light, speed, vision, thought-experiment

I was thinking about superluminal travel when thinking about advanced civilisations in the future.

I was also thinking about the Doppler effect; so I decided to think about how light may be affected in a similar way (besides redshift).

I was thinking about thing appearing to go back in time (when looking from behind a superluminal object), but then I found a fundamental flaw with that thought - any light that had previously hit the object before it travelled at such superluminal speeds would not somehow radiate out of the object again, therefore rendering everything behind invisible (shown in this diagram):

[image: v=c]

(The circles represent light waves that would radiate from the source if it were luminous.)

But then I thought: "If I went past light speed, and onto higher speeds altogether, would I have further limitations of vision?"

Here is another diagram of that:

[image: v=xc]

**My question:**

If superluminal travel were possible, then would the "funnel of vision" be possible, and if so, how would we see it? Would we see it as a small, bluish (due to the Doppler effect) circle with darkness surrounding it or would light seem to bend, blueshift and contort itself?

Comment: I recall reading in a "Science of Science Fiction"-type book that as a spaceship sped up to near the speed of light, the starfield would contract into a cluster in front of the ship.  The faster the ship went, the smaller the cluster got.  No mention of superluminal speed, though, presumably since the book didn't want to bother addressing "impossible" circumstances.

Comment: If you were traveling at superluminal speed your eyes would have increased mass. You'd probably be blind due to them collapsing at some point, so that's how much your vision would be impaired ;)

Comment: Ah, surprised to see that my topic is on hold. Hmm... ..if it doesn't belong here, then where else must this go? I can't find any way to edit it and keep true to the topic of the post. Should I try Space Exploration?